# how to get event when user scroll to top in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

could you please tell me how to get event when user scroll to top .Actually I am using ng-repeat in my example .I want to get event when user scroll to bottom and scroll to top .I have one div in which I used ng-repeat can we get event of top when user move to top after scrolling.Actually I need to show alert when user scroll to bottom and top of div in angular .here is my code

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
<div style="width:90%;height:150px;border:1px solid red;overflow:auto">
<div ng-repeat="n in name">{{n.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use ion scroll's on scroll event. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/

Comment: how I will get event of scroll top and bottom

Answer (score 6):

You could put directives on your scrollable div that listen to the `scroll` event and check for the top or bottom being reached.

So, using your HTML, your div would look like this:

```
<div exec-on-scroll-to-top="ctrl.handleScrollToTop"
     exec-on-scroll-to-bottom="ctrl.handleScrollToBottom"
     style="width:90%;height:150px;border:1px solid red;overflow:auto">
  <div ng-repeat="n in name">{{n.name}}</div>
</div>
```

With new directives `exec-on-scroll-to-top` and `exec-on-scroll-to-bottom` added. Each specifies a function in your controller that should execute when the particular event the directive is checking for occurs.

`exec-on-scroll-to-top` would look like this, just checking for the scrollable div's `scrollTop` property to be `0`:

```
myapp.directive('execOnScrollToTop', function () {

  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var fn = scope.$eval(attrs.execOnScrollToTop);

      element.on('scroll', function (e) {

        if (!e.target.scrollTop) {
          console.log("scrolled to top...");
          scope.$apply(fn);
        }

      });
    }

  };

});
```

And `exec-on-scroll-to-bottom` would look like this (keeping in mind that an element is fully scrolled when its `(scrollHeight - scrollTop) === clientHeight`):

```
myapp.directive('execOnScrollToBottom', function () {

  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var fn = scope.$eval(attrs.execOnScrollToBottom),
          clientHeight = element[0].clientHeight;

      element.on('scroll', function (e) {
        var el = e.target;

        if ((el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop) === clientHeight) { // fully scrolled
          console.log("scrolled to bottom...");
          scope.$apply(fn);
        }
      });
    }

  };

});
```

[Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vG6znUWU3QOTqv5wqrMb?p=preview). Open the console to see messages getting logged when the scrolling reaches the top or bottom.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non angular way, but you can wrap it up in a directive which also allows reuse:

Use Javascript event listener:

```
div.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(this.scrollTop===0)
    //do your stuff
```

});

Make sure to use `$apply` if you make any changes to the scope variables inside this listener.

Comment: but I need for angular js.please remove your answer,..!!